# Find function based on table of values

Tags: functions, derivatives, polynomials

I have the following table and would like to know if it is possible to find the passing function:

$$
\begin{array}{| r | r | r |}
x& f(x)& f'(x)\\
\hline
-2 & 7 & 13\\
-1 & 8 & 11\\
 0 & 13 & -13\\
1 & -8 & 11\\
2 &-6&-10
\end{array}
$$

Then I have to compute $$h(x)=\frac{-6x^2-6x-12}{f(x)}$$ for $$h'(2)$$.

The answer should be $$\frac{55}{3}$$

Comment: There are many functions that satisfy your assumptions. Try a polynomial in x. What degree should it have?

Comment: I'm not sure, the question goes like this: Given the the following table  and $$h(x)=\frac{-6x^2-6x-12}{f(x)}$$compute h'(2)

Comment: Use the chain rule for that.  You don't need to know the actual function.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks, i'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comment, the user updated their question to say that the original problem is

$$ h(x) = \frac{-6x^2 - 6x - 12}{f(x)} $$.

He is trying to compute $h'(2)$.  To do this, you first find the derivative of $h(x)$, which is found using the quotient rule and the chain rule:

$$ h'(x) = \frac{f(x)\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(-6x^2 - 6x - 12\right)\right) - \left(-6x^2 - 6x - 12\right)f'(x)}{(f(x))^2} \\
h'(x) = \frac{f(x)(-12x - 6) + f'(x)(6x^2 + 6x + 12)}{(f(x))^2}
$$
At $x = 2$, using the given table, this is:
$$ h'(x) = \frac{(-6)(-12(2) - 6) + (-10)(6(2)^2 + 6(2) + 12)}{(-6)^2}$$

If I entered all that correctly, the result is $-\frac{25}{3}$.

Comment: Pretty weird I also found $$-\frac{25}{3}$$ but my textbook says it is $$\frac{55}{3}$$

Comment: I think your textbook missed a sign somewhere.  If $f'(x) = 10$ (instead of -10), you get $\frac{55}{3}$.  That either means (a) you typed the sign wrong above, (b) they got the sign wrong in the book, or (c), they forgot to subtract the right-hand part of the quotient rule.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the initial question, if you want a polynomial, its maximum degree is $9$ since you have $10$ conditions. Writing
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^9 a_i x^i$$ looking at the values at $x=0$, we know that $a_0=13$ and $a_1=-13$. The other parameters are easily obtained using matrix calculation.

If I am not mistaken, the coefficients are
$$\left\{13,-13,-\frac{6937}{216},-\frac{3317}{864},\frac{3737}{144},\frac{15917}{1152},-\frac{68}{9},-\frac{
   3235}{576},\frac{311}{432},\frac{2207}{3456}\right\}$$